# Unable to download Office 365 SharePoint library item

Tags: c#, .net, office365

I am trying to download item that exists in Office 365 SharePoint library using `WebcClient.DownloadFile()` but i am getting this exception:

Exception :

```
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Sample code :

```
NetworkCredential credential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "aaa.onmicrosoft.com");
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Credentials = credential;
webClient.DownloadFile(@"https://aaa.sharepoint.com/testDoc/test.pdf", @"c:/test.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of help from my friends, I've managed to crack this SharePoint on-line authentication stuff :)

I was kindly pointed in the direction of [this blog post](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx) from Wictor Wilén.

And my WebClient call that uses Wictors claims library code...

```
var claimsHelper = new MsOnlineClaimsHelper(sharepointOnlineUrl, username, password);

var client = new WebClient();
client.Headers[ "Accept" ] = "/";
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, claimsHelper.CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(new Uri(sharepointOnlineUrl))  );

var document = client.DownloadString( documentUrl );
```

Comment: How do you put the `var document` to the user as download?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... the example above obtains the document (in my case an xml file) as a string, this string (var document) can then be pushed into a db or consumed as you need...
Using your example above.. just change my client.DownloadString(...) to client.DownloadFile(...)

Comment: I'm getting a nullreference exception on the cookiecontainer: `[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Wictor.Office365.MsOnlineClaimsHelper.getCookieContainer() +128
   Wictor.Office365.MsOnlineClaimsHelper.get_CookieContainer() +322
   Upmyapp._Default.function1() +275
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177
`

Comment: Yup.. I found that the wrong credentials or wrong url caused a COM plus exception deeper in the helper library :(

Comment: I guess it's just the opposite of a get (PUT) perhaps.. you should probably open a new question for that one ;)

Comment: @andywck I've deployed my application online. But I have the nullreference cookiecontainer exception back.
Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to copy the Sharepoint and Identity model dlls local on build ;)

Comment: you were right. I've fixed it by manually FTPíng the Microsoft.identitymodel.dll to the right folder

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to utilize [SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) from  [SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038).

[SharePointOnlineCredentials class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx) represents an object that provides credentials to access SharePoint Online resources

### Prerequisites

[SharePoint Online Client Components SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

### How to download a file from SharePoint Online

```
 public static void DownloadFile(string userName, string password, string fileUrl, string filePath)
 {
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (var c in password)
        {
            securePassword.AppendChar(c);
        }
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
            client.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
            client.DownloadFile(fileUrl, filePath);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a little bit to get rid of your issue, called Headers and UserAgent.

```
 public static void method()
        {
         //   NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "aaa.onmicrosoft.com");
            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            var ua = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
            w.Headers["Accept"] = "/";
            w.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, ua);
            w.Credentials = myCredentials;
          w.DownloadFile(url, @"c:/name.doc"); 
        }
```

It downloads the file for me from the teamsite library in office 365. But it gives me a downloaded file. Only issue I have left : the file does not contain the real information you wish to download. I'm trying to solve this issue for a few days now - and this is the best result I've gotten up to now.
Maybe you could help me on that with this new information.
Let me know please :)

Comment: Have you had any joy with this.. I'm having similar issues :(

Comment: I also got the wrong data in my file. Vadim's answer (setting the X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED header) did it for me).